# Python Tkinter, can I limit the number of entry?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can I limit the number of user inputs such that if the user has wrongly tried 5 times already, the system will end immediately?

I have tried to use While loop as usual to achieve. However, the while loop seems to be unable to calculate the number of incorrect input.

Please let me know what should I do. Appreciate

```
import tkinter as tk
import csv
from tkinter import messagebox


def user_login():
    locals()
    entry_user_name = entry_usr_name.get()
    entry_user_pwd = entry_usr_pwd.get()

    with open(r'user.csv', 'r') as user_file
         reader = csv.reader(user_file)
         user = list(reader)
    found = False
    count1 = 5
    for count in range(len(user)):
         if entry_user_name == user[count][0]:
              if entry_user_pwd == user[count][1]:
                 target = count
                 found = True
                 break
              else: found = False
         else: found = False
               count1 -= 1
    if not found:
              tk.messagebox.showerror(title='Error',
                                      message='Invalid password. Please enter again. You have '+str(count1)+ ' left')
    if count1 == 0:
              tk.messagebox.showerror(title='Error',
                                line1='Too many input. The system will be ended immediately',
                                line2='This will be recorded in the security system')
    if found:
         tk.messagebox.showinfo(title='Successful login',
                                message='Valid password.')
    startpage()



window = tk.Tk()
entry_username = tk.Entry(window, font='Courier 17')
entry_pwd = tk.Entry(window,font='Courier 17')
entry_usr_name.place(x=330, y=245)
entry_usr_pwd.place(x=330, y=345)

login_button= tk.Button(window,
                        command=user_login) # with some setting
login_button.place(x=440, y=420)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: show me how you tried to implement the while loop

Comment: This is just basic logic. Every time they submit the inputs, update a counter. Then, check the value of the counter and call an appropriate function if the number is too big.

Comment: Please wait a minute. I am now updating with my code.

Comment: I am confused where should I put my while loop in

Comment: You don't need a while loop.

Comment: Thank you. I think I know how to do by if condition. Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tracking variable to keep record of how many attempts a person has made.

Here is a simple example.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

counter = 1 # tracking variable

tk.Label(root, text="User Name: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Password: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
entry_name = tk.Entry(root)
entry_pass = tk.Entry(root)
entry_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_pass.grid(row=1, column=1)


def check_login():
    global counter, entry_name, entry_pass
    x = entry_name.get()
    y = entry_pass.get()
    if counter <= 5: # if counter 5 or less then check login info
        if x == "Bob" and y == "mypassword":
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            counter += 1 # add 1 to counter
            print("Bad login! Please try again")
    else:
        print("Exceeded max attempt.")

tk.Button(root, text="Login", command=check_login).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Appreciate. You remind me that I have wrongly placed the tracking variable.

Comment: @7vinBB keep in mind that while loops and Tkinter tend to not work together. Tkinter is event driven and uses `mainloop()` to manage the events. If you get stuck in a while loop you end up blocking the `mainloop()`.